# c# radio button bound to model; checked state styling css

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to style these radio buttons with css for their "checked state". I've styled every other state except checked and I've done some digging on switching these to input type="radio" since they seem easier to style but haven't discovered a way to keep them bound to the model. See code below:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="btn-group" id="roles_select" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.recipientTypeId, "Assign Notification To: ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                <label class="btn btn-primary roles" id="admin">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.recipientTypeId, "2")Admin
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary roles" id="candidate">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.recipientTypeId, "1")Candidate
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary col-md-push-0 roles" id="manager">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.recipientTypeId, "3")Manager
                </label>
      </div>
</div>
```

code from controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {

        ViewBag.recipientTypeId = new SelectList(db.RecipientType, "Id", "recipientRole");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,notificationType1,recipientTypeId,frequency")] NotificationType notificationType)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(notificationType).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        ViewBag.recipientTypeId = new SelectList(db.RecipientType, "Id", "frequency", "recipientRole", notificationType.recipientTypeId);
        return View(notificationType);
    }
```

CSS Snipped (not working)

```
#roles_select input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Model binding and css are completely unrelated. If its not binding then its due to other issues with your code. Show you model and the controller code.

Comment: `input[type="radio"]:checked + label` means style the `<label>` element **immediately after ** the `<radio checked />` element (your radio buttons are wrapped in labels - not after)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `jquery`.

All you need to trigger an `change` event handler to `radio` buttons.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
     $('input[type="radio"]').removeClass('radioChecked');
     $(this).addClass('radioChecked'); 
});
```

Your css:

```
.radiocheck { color: black; background-color:black; }
```

Here is my example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsYqx/4723/).

Comment: didn't work unfortunately. Here is the css that was tried as a test with class syntax above: `.radiocheck:checked {
    color: black;
    background-color:black;
}'

Comment: the styling works but it's not bound to my model so the selections aren't being input into the database

Comment: Can your post your function from server-side ?

Comment: You dont need jquery for this - you can just style it using `input[type=checkbox]:checked { ... }`

Comment: Yes, I know this.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai sorry for the delay. I've added the code from the controller recent css code i've tried. All other styling works like ':hover' and ':active'. The only issue left is styling for checked. I tried the jquery you suggested as well but it didn't work on my end.